# Getting an error: The "SignAppxPackage" task failed unexpectedly while trying to create App Packages

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, sign, windows-store

I'm trying to create an app package to be uploaded to the Store. I right clicked on the Project then Store>Create App Packages...

Then I get the following error:

> The "SignAppxPackage" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified
>   executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.SignAppxPackage.SignFile(String
>   certFilePath, String certificateThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String
>   path)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.SignAppxPackage.ExecuteImplementation()
>   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.SignAppxPackage.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

And this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Task 'SignAppxPackage' failed. The specified executable is not
>   a valid application for this OS platform. Pegasus

I'm running on:

Windows 10

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (Version 14.0.24720.00)

App Project (Windows 8.1)

This only happens when I'm creating an AppPackage for Windows 8.1 projects. If it's a Universal App, there's no problem.

Comment: Did you try creating app package with VS 2013?

Comment: I don't have visual studio 2013. I used to be able to create an app package for Windows 8.1 before I update to VS2015 Update 1. Now I'm trying to reinstall VS2015 without the update 1.

Comment: I got it working again I guess it's just in the setup of visual studio. I tried to re install visual studio and it worked just fine.